# Relations of equivalence...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Given the set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

How can I establish how many and what are the equivalence relations $R$ on $A$ that meet all the following conditions?

1) $|A/R| = 3$

2) $1 R 2$

3) $[2]_R\neq[3]_R$

4) $[4]_R = [5]_R$

5) $|[7]_R| = 3$

Comment: Equivalence relations on $A$ correspond one to one with partitions of $A$ and the elements of the partition are the equivalence classes. It is handsome to focus on the partitions. In 1) you are told that the corresponding partition contains $3$ sets, in 2) that $1,2$ belong to the same equivalence class (element of partition) and so on. You will end up with some possibilities by discerning cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [partition and equivalence relation are equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Partitions_and_equivalence_relations), it suffices to consider the ways to partition $A$.

1. $|A/{\cal R}| = 3$: there are three partitions
2. $1 {\cal R} 2$: $1$ and $2$ are in the same partition
3. $ [2]_{\cal R} \ne [3]_{\cal R}$: $2$ and $3$ are in different partitions
4. $[4]_{\cal R} = [5]_{\cal R}$: $4$ and $5$ are in the same partition
5. $|[7]_{\cal R}|=3$: partition $[7]_{\cal R}$ has three elements.

We start with $\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{\}\}$.

- $[4]_{\cal R} = [1]_{\cal R}$
  This gives $\{\{1,2,4,5\},\{3\},\{\}\}$.  Wherever we put $7$, property (5) is violated.
- $[4]_{\cal R} = [3]_{\cal R}$
  From $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\},\{\}\}$ and property (5), the only choice is $\{\{1,2,7\},\{3,4,5\},\{6\}\}$.
- Otherwise, $\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4,5\}\}$.  Use property (5) again.

  - When $7$ is in the first or the third partition, $6$ can be in either of the other two partitions.
  - When $7$ is in the second partition, then so as $6$.

We have $1+2\times2+1=6$ choices.
\begin{align}
& \{\{1,2,7\},\{3,4,5\},\{6\}\} \\
& \{\{1,2,7\},\{3,6\},\{4,5\}\} \\
& \{\{1,2,7\},\{3\},\{4,5,6\}\} \\
& \{\{1,2\},\{3,6,7\},\{4,5\}\} \\
& \{\{1,2,6\},\{3\},\{4,5,7\}\} \\
& \{\{1,2\},\{3,6\},\{4,5,7\}\} \\
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't understand the 1+2x2+1 part, how did you come up with that equation?

Comment: @JonD The first case is from the 2nd bullet point.  The $2 \times 2$ is from the two choices of $7$ and the two choices of $6$.